# What exactly is the meaning of "wait-free" in boost::lockfree?

Tags: c++, boost, nonblocking, lock-free, wait-free

I am reading the docs for [spsc_queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html) and even after reading a bit elsewhere I am not completely convinced about the meaning of "wait-free".

What exactly do they mean here

> bool push(T const & t);
>
> Pushes object t to the ringbuffer.
>
> Note: Thread-safe and wait-free

I mean there must be some overhead for synchronisation. Is

```
some_spscqueue.push(x);
```

guaranteed to take a constant amount of time? How does it compare to a non-thread safe queue?

PS: dont worry, I am going to measure, but due to my naive ignorance I just cant imagine a synchronisation mechanism that does not involve some kind of waiting and I am quite puzzled what "wait-free" is supposed to tell me.

Comment: Have you tried  wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm

Comment: @NeilButterworth yes I did, but for example "An algorithm is wait-free if every operation has a bound on the number of steps the algorithm will take before the operation completes." I dont completely understand how this is different from using locks plus being sure that there is no chance of deadlock.

Comment: In principle, you're still missing starvation from that - wait-free algorithms can't be starved, but mutexes easily can be (ie, they generally don't exhibit "fair" scheduling behaviour under high contention). In practice, the cost of a mutex is higher (due to parking and the waiter queue). There are some situations where you _want_ parking, and it's a benefit, but pushing to a queue is probably not one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A wait-free implementation of a concurrent data object is one that guarantees that any process can complete any operation in a finite number of steps, regardless of the execution speeds of the other processes.

(from the [abstract](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=102808) of the Herlihy article).

See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm#Wait-freedom), and all the other resources you immediately find by typing "wait free" into a search engine.

So *wait-free* doesn't mean *no delay*, it means you never enter a blocking wait-state, and can't be indefinitely blocked and/or starved.

In other words, *wait* has the specific technical meaning that your thread is either parked (and does not execute any instructions until something wakes it up), or is in a loop waiting for some external condition to be satisfied (eg. a spinlock). If it's never woken up, or if it is woken up but always finds it can't proceed and has to *wait* again, or if the loop never exits, then your thread is being starved and cannot make progress.

Every operation has *some* latency, and wait-free doesn't say *anything* about what that is.

> How does it compare to a non-thread safe queue?

It'll almost certainly be more expensive than a wholly-unsynchronized container, because you're still doing extra work (assuming you really do only access the container from a single thread).

Comment: so the main difference compared to using mutexes is that there is no chance to run into a deadlock, but in the worst case a lock-free push may take as long as one using locks?

Comment: It will almost certainly be faster than a mutex. It's likely to be about as long as the initial spinlock part of an adaptive mutex, but without ever parking, and without the expensive unlock/wakeup path. However, this does mean more threads actually doing stuff, which in some cases slows down the overall system.

Comment: ok thanks, your edit made it more clear. I think I will just try and see. The question I didnt ask because i thought it is too broad / not specific is how to guarantee that the producer wont block. Lets see how far I can get with a wait-free queue....

Comment: @Useless careful with those generalizations, there are enough situations where a locking algorithm can be much faster than a lockless algorithm. Most people confuse "lockless" and co with "faster". While that can be true for specific situations, locks can be exceedingly efficient and I've seen 95%+ dropped updates with CAS on contended systems.

Comment: Yep, agreed. Wait-free style has less work to do in the uncontended case, _if_ the container or algorithm fit it well. If there's contention, or if the container or algorithm don't naturally suit wait-free style, then mutexes can easily take the lead again.

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer (well the Herlihy quote is obviously right, but not the rest). _Wait_ isn't about the thread parking.  That is more like _blocked_ (either parked or spinning on a spin lock).

Comment: @Voo wait-free algorithms can have CAS but not CAS-loops (which is the typical use case of CAS).  So they are much less likely to run into contention problems - that's the beauty of wait-free.  But yes, lock-free (et al) doesn't equal faster.  Only measuring can answer that.

Answer (score 0):

"Pushes object to the ring buffer" refers to the type of array buffer that the queue is implemented on. This is probably implemented using a circular array to store the objects in the queue. See for example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer

and

http://opendatastructures.org/ods-python/2_3_ArrayQueue_Array_Based_.html

Comment: the question was specifically about the meaning of "wait-free". I know what "push" means and what a queue is. Sorry if this wasnt clear